# Surface touchpad not working

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro

Sometimes my Surface Pro 4 touchpad stops working when I resume from sleep. The keys on the type cover still work, just no responsiveness from the touchpad.

[Microsoft support](https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/hardware-and-drivers/troubleshoot-surface-keyboards?os=windows-10) recommends reattaching the cover, getting the latest updates (have them), or restarting the machine.

Restarting usually does the trick, but it's obviously very annoying to do so. Is there some way I can get it to recognize the touchpad again without a full restart? Maybe some trickery in the device manager or the registry?

Comment: If their suggestion does not work I suggest a warranty claim

Answer (score 2):

A large class of device enumeration problems can be recovered from by cycling through "Disable"/"Enable" on the device in Device Manager.  (Although this may by more annoying than detaching/reattaching the keyboard/touchpad).  This can be done from a command line script if you are willing to install DevCon:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544707(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: I don't understand why you would say that adding another option likely to achieve what the user wants (with its own associated pros and cons), that the user had not considered, is not an answer.  Specifically go to Device Manager, click on the device, disable it, wait until its done, enable it.  (I have since learned of DevCon which can probably do this from a script.)  In fact, the user invited a solution involving "trickery" and Device Manager, which is exactly what I suggest.

Comment: Maybe you assumed that this was the same as detaching/reattaching.  I believe that (in this context) is referring to mechanically and electrically separating the tablet CPU from the optional keyboard, and then reattaching.

Comment: No, my comment was related to 1/ "You can probably". and 2/ "I'd look into whether this can be done from a command line script" Something which implies you are not sure does not make a good answer.

Comment: I suppose so.  But the "probably" I'm referring to is completely because I don't have the hardware to recreate the exact scenario in question.  I think if you apply that standard to responses on this site in general, almost ALL the answers should include "probably."  In this case, we won't really know if it is useful until the user tries it, or until someone documents the bug to the point where we can predict whether enable/disable will address the problem.  Maybe you have access to Microsoft source code?

Comment: I wonder if you will find my edits satisfying now.  But note:  you are not improving the quality of answers by encouraging them to be written with overconfidence.  Do you verify that those who "are sure" are justifiably sure?

Comment: Please reread my  comments. If you are **not sure** it should be **a comment not an answer**. If you are sure (speaking from experience) then fine.

Comment: OK.  I guess I'll recalibrate for reading this site then.  An answer that sounds sure, is just sounding sure so that it won't get demoted.  I don't yet know how to recognize answers that are actually correct--maybe those obsessive enough to spend hours creating and testing, so that limits the scope of knowledge you can draw on to those with no real job and ADD, but it is great to get all this understood.

Comment: By the way, I'd be glad to start with a comment instead of an answer, but your system tells me I need 50 reputation to comment--seems kind of backwards.

Comment: Mike don't let a rough start with comment/answer convention keep you away from further contributions. Your answer is indeed useful.